# Ajax XML Update every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I have made an Ajax XML script that will open a XML file, find an attribute value and display it in a DIV.
it will do this every 10 seconds as the XML file is updated frequently.

I have run into an issue where it will stop working after a few hours, i think there may be a memory leak or such but im unsure, to be honest im not even sure if i am looping it correctly, and advice would be appreciated.

```js
function getXML() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "assets/alerts.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: function (xml) {

      var fireXML = $(xml).find('template').eq(0).attr("name");
      var lightXML = $(xml).find('template').eq(1).attr("name");

      var fire = new Array();
      fire['FIRE_CLEAR'] = "Clear";
      fire['FIRE_BLUE'] = "Blue";
      fire['FIRE_YELLOW'] = "Yellow";
      fire['FIRE_RED'] = "Red";
      var firealert = fire[fireXML];
      $('#firealert').html(firealert);

      var light = new Array();
      light['GLC_CLEAR'] = "Clear";
      light['GLC_BLUE'] = "Blue";
      light['GLC_YELLOW'] = "Yellow";
      light['GLC_RED'] = "Red";
      var lightalert = light[lightXML];
      $('#lightningalert').html(lightalert);

      setTimeout(getXML, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This executes every second, not every 10 seconds

Comment: With no error handling as per previous comment you have no chance to debug your code

Comment: You also seem to be mis-using JS arrays. I think `fire` and `light` should be objects, ie `var fire = {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you do not handle failure, so you need to add something like:

```
error: function() {
           setTimeout(getXML, 1000);
       }
```

This will ensure the timer restarts after an error.